# How to combine Filling with Manipulate in the given code to illustrate the total area that the lines cover?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, color, filling

I have three functions $f(x,y)\,,g(x,y,z)\,,h(x,y,z)\,$

```
f[x_, y_] := Cos[x Sqrt[y]] + ((1 + 2 Sqrt[y] Cot[Sqrt[y]]) Sin[x Sqrt[y]])/( 2 Sqrt[y]);
g[x_, y_, z_] := 1/(4 Sqrt[y]) Csc[Sqrt[y]/2] Sec[Sqrt[y]/ 2] (2 Sqrt[y] Cos[x Sqrt[y]] Sin[Sqrt[y]] + 2 Sqrt[y] Cos[Sqrt[y]] Sin[x Sqrt[y]] -2 Sqrt[y] Cos[z] Sin[x Sqrt[y]] + 3 Sin[Sqrt[y]] Sin[x Sqrt[y]] + Sqrt[y] Sin[Sqrt[ y]] \[Sqrt](1/ y (-4 y +  4 y Cos[  x Sqrt[y]]^2 + (3 + 2 Sqrt[y] Cot[Sqrt[y]] -  2 Sqrt[y] Cos[z] Csc[Sqrt[y]])^2 Sin[x Sqrt[y]]^2 +  6 Sqrt[y] Sin[2 x Sqrt[y]] +  4 y Cot[Sqrt[y]] Sin[2 x Sqrt[y]] -  4 y Cos[z] Csc[Sqrt[y]] Sin[2 x Sqrt[y]])));
h[x_, y_, z_] := 1/(4 Sqrt[y]) Csc[Sqrt[y]/2] Sec[Sqrt[y]/ 2] (2 Sqrt[y] Cos[x Sqrt[y]] Sin[Sqrt[y]] + 2 Sqrt[y] Cos[Sqrt[y]] Sin[x Sqrt[y]] -2 Sqrt[y] Cos[z] Sin[x Sqrt[y]] + 3 Sin[Sqrt[y]] Sin[x Sqrt[y]] + 2 Sqrt[y] Sin[Sqrt[ y]] \[Sqrt](1/ y (-4 y + 4 y Cos[x Sqrt[y]]^2 + (3 + 2 Sqrt[y] Cot[Sqrt[y]] - 2 Sqrt[y] Cos[z] Csc[Sqrt[y]])^2 Sin[x Sqrt[y]]^2 +  6 Sqrt[y] Sin[2 x Sqrt[y]] +4 y Cot[Sqrt[y]] Sin[2 x Sqrt[y]] -  4 y Cos[z] Csc[Sqrt[y]] Sin[2 x Sqrt[y]])));
```

I am using `Manipulate` to show those points $(x,y)$ for which we have $f(x,y)=g(x,y,z)$ and $f(x,y)=h(x,y,z)\;$ as $z$ changes from zero to $1$; using this code

```
Manipulate[ 
Show[ ContourPlot[f[x, y] == g[x, y, z], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 2, 9},  ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.006]],  PlotPoints -> 30 , RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y},  x != 0 && Im[g[x, y, z]] == 0 && -1 < g[x, y, z] < 0]], 
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == h[x, y, z], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 2, 9}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Green, Thickness[0.006]],  PlotPoints -> 30 , RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y},  x != 0 && Im[h[x, y, z]] == 0 && -1 < h[x, y, z] < 0]]] 
, {z, 0, 1}]
```

I get this result

[image]

**Question:**
Is it possible to combine `Filling` with this `Manipulate` code to illustrate the total area that the black and green lines travel as $z$ changes from zero to $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly.

If you intend to illustrate the "area of all green lines" proceed as follows:
Calculate some green lines for 0<z<1

```
pic = ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[f[x, y] == g[x, y, z] , {z, 0, 1, 1/8}], {x, 0, 
4}, {y, 2, 9} , PlotPoints -> 30 ,RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, -1 < f[x, y ] < 0] ];
pg = Cases[Normal[pic], Line[p_] :> p, -1] ;(* all green points*)
cloud = Graphics[{Lighter[Green, .9 ], Map[Point, pg, 1]} ] (* point cloud *)
```

`Manipulate`( modified, with simplified `RegionFunction`):

```
Manipulate[Show [{cloud, 
ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == g[x, y, z], f[x, y] == h[x, y, z]}, {x, 0,4}, {y, 2, 9}, ContourStyle -> {Black , Green}, PlotPoints -> 30 , 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, -1 < f[x, y ] < 0] ]}]  , {z,0, 1}]
```

[image]

In the same way a "cloud for the black curves" might be calculated. But both clouds overlap therefore it makes no sense to show  both clouds  in one plot.

Hope it helps!